# SSRS culture overwrited

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, reporting-services

I am using ReportViewer for MVC to display my SSRS(2008) report in my web application (ASP.NET MVC). In my web.config file, I set the culture to french:

```xml
< system.web>
    ...
    < globalization uiCulture="fr" culture="fr-CA" />
</ system.web>
```

When I run my application on localhost, my report is displayed in French. But when I publish my site on another server, with the IIS Edit .NET Globalization Settings culture set to Canadian French (fr-CA), the report is displayed in English ('View Report' button for example).

I added these line in my `Global.asax.cs` file but it didn't solve my problem:

```vb
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Any suggestion on how I can have my report displayed in french?

Comment: Can you verify that the Thread.CurentCulture is being set to fr-CA?

Comment: I just defined Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture  and CurrenUICulture in my Global.asax.cs and publiched. Still in english..